# Difference between mod_authn_ldap and mod_authz_ldap

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

What is the difference between the `mod_authnz_ldap` and `mod_authz_ldap` loadable modules for the Apache web server?

Comment: In Apache httpd 2.2 there is only mod_authnz_ldap (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html). What do you want to know exactly?

Comment: For example, `ls /etc/httpd/conf.d/modules/*ldap*` on CentOS 6 shows `mod_authnz_ldap.so`, `mod_authz_ldap.so`, and `mod_ldap.so`—_three_ different loadable modules with no obvious difference between them. Two are actually part of the `httpd-2.2x` package and one is owned by the `mod_authz_ldap` package.

Answer (score 9):

There is no such thing called [mod_authn_ldap](http://www.google.com/search?q=mod_authn_ldap+site%3Ahttpd.apache.org). There is only [mod_authnz_ldap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html).

In versions of Apache before Apache2.2, the modules for "Access Control"  were all called 'mod_authsomething'.

Apache 2.2 split the Auth* modules into modules which would keep authentication and authorization separate. See the Apache documentation, [Authentication, Authorization and Access Control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) for a summary.

- A mod_authn_* module will provide Authentication services (Hence the name 'authn')
- A mod_authz_* module will provide Authorization services (Hence the name 'authz')
- A mod_authnz_* module will provide both Authentication and Authorization.

mod_authnz_ldap is one of the few modules which provides both Authorization and Authentication. This can be confusing and can be a hassle when trying to integrate with other services.

It is very important to learn and understand the difference between [Authentication vs. Authorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication#Authentication_vs._authorization), especially with respect to security of LDAP, Apache webserver, PAM, etc.

- Authentication determines that you are who you claim to be.
- Authorization determines if you have the right to do something.

Answer (score 1):

From memory these were the modules that handled the LDAP password checking and group membership checking functions, that were combined into [mod_authnz_ldap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html).  The authn module performed authentication (is the user valid?) and authz checked authorisation (is the user permitted to access this?).  My memory could be fuzzy here though.